# Installing styled components failed in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native 0.63.4 and react 16.13.1.
I try to install 'styled-components' with

`npm install --save styled-components`

and failed with these messages:

```
`code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: myproject@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@16.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">= 16.8.0" from styled-components@5.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/styled-components
npm ERR!     styled-components@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@">= 16.8.0" from styled-components@5.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/styled-components
npm ERR!     styled-components@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! `
```

I was not sure what the problems are.
Please if anyone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: are you try install another library?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2120

Also there is a issue with npm resolving peer-dependencies, npm-CLI currently breaks standard NPM7 installs of several major dependencies, such as for example styled-component, your npm version is 7.+ also

Try downgrading to npm 6 or install another version of styled-components

or you can use yarn to install styled-components

```
yarn add styled-components
```

Comment: Why do they need react dom on React Native? [Styled Components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#installation) does not say this in their installation guide. I think this will add a redundant library in the codebase

Comment: kindly check this error , it says unable to resolve dependency from react-dom.

Comment: check following page, react-dom is used by styled components for server-side rendering ,https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Comment: React dom is installed --> 7.4.2

Comment: sorry! my mistake that was npm version, not react-dom version, I have successfully installed styled-component in my PC, I have npm 6.4, while yours is 7.4.2, there is a reported issue  in npm7 installs, you can try something like downgrading your npm version to 6.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using yarn to instal styled-components, and it works.

```
yarn add styled-components
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using yarn instead of npm?